# How to outputting of text data to an external temp file?

Tags: javascript

In the following example, data lines are written to a textarea. However, this leads to a DOM overload, so the browser gets slower and slower. To solve this problem, I would like to write the data externally to a Temp. From there the lines should then be transferred back to the textarea. Can somebody help me with it ? Thanks very much!!

```js
var btnWrite = document.getElementById("writeElement");
var btnStop = document.getElementById("stopElement");
var btnClear = document.getElementById("clearElement");
var btnSave = document.getElementById("saveElement");
  
btnWrite.addEventListener("click", writeData);
btnStop.addEventListener("click", stopText);
btnClear.addEventListener("click", clearText);
btnSave.addEventListener("click", saveText);

textareaStatus = document.body.appendChild( document.createElement( 'textarea' ) );

var timer = null; 

function writeData() {
    var text = ((0.1111111111*10).toFixed(6) + " " + (0.2222222222*10).toFixed(6) + " " + (0.3333333333*10).toFixed(6) + " " + (0.4444444444*10).toFixed(6) + " " + (0.5555555555*10).toFixed(6) + " " + (0.6666666666*10).toFixed(6) + " " + (0.7777777777*10).toFixed(6) +" "+ (0.8888888888*10).toFixed(6) + " " + (0.9999999999*10).toFixed(6) + "\n");
    timer = setTimeout(writeData, 1000.000);
    textareaStatus.value += text;

/*
    var path = "c:\\Temp\\Test.txt";
    var data = text;
   
    WriteFile(path, data, function(error) {
        if (error) {
            console.error("write error:  " + error.message);
        } else {
            console.log("Successful Write to " + path);
        }
    });
*/     
}

function stopText() {
    clearTimeout(timer);
    LineCounter();    
}  

function clearText() {
    frames = 0;
    textareaStatus.value = "";
    LineCounter() == "";
}

function saveText() {
    var txt = exampleFile;  //this file is available with me. 
    txt += textareaStatus.value; 
    var blob = new Blob( [ txt ] , {type: "text/plain;charset=utf-8"} );
    saveAs( blob, "File000.txt" );  
} 

function LineCounter() {   
    var lineBreaksCount = (textareaStatus.value.split('\n'));
    document.getElementById("LineCounter").innerHTML = (lineBreaksCount.length)-1;
}
```

```css
textarea { 
    display: block; 
    font-size:small;
    color: #ffffff;
    margin-top:5px;
    margin-left:1px; 
    width: 500px;                             
    height:100px; 
    overflow: auto;
    white-space: pre;
    background: black;
}
```

```html
<div class="count">Lines = <span id="LineCounter">0</span><div> 
 
<button id="writeElement">Write</button> 
<button id="stopElement">Stop</button>
<button id="saveElement">Save</button>
<button id="clearElement">Clear</button>
```

Comment: You might want to look into the IndexedDb browser Api, it's avaliable in most modern browsers and gives you database like storage that is persistent. If you shut down computer etc. it will still be there next time you visit the site.

Comment: ***@David Sherman*** Thank you for your answer, it does not need to be saved, actually it would be enough if I could write it in the console and get it from there again. Also in the DOM I need the values only to export them from there. It will therefore be deleted immediately in the DOM. Everything temporary! Thank you for the tip.

Comment: In that case you can just keep it in a javascript variable and choose how and when to add it to the DOM. You cannot write to any file system from the browser, this is strictly prohibited for security reasons (websites writing virusesses to your computer as soon  as you visit them etc.)

Comment: ***David Sherman*** yes, this with the security, I have noticed  : -(  this is not a good idea of mine. What they say is interesting, maybe they have an example for that? Then the whole amount of data would be left in the variable, until I load it into the DOM via SaveButton and write it into a file.

Comment: What is the purpose of the code, what is the problem you are trying to solve?
As far as I understand so far you are trying to add text to a text area and keep track of the amount of lines, but are running into performance issues when the text gets to long. Am I correct?

Comment: It's working now, thanks for the tipps.