# How can a value be limited to six digits and multiplied by 10 at the same time?

Tags: javascript

The example gives unreliable results, depending on the number used its the result correct, and then again not. my values are all in the range of 0.10000000000 to 0.99999999999 thats too smal, they should be in the range of 1.000000 to 9.000000, so reduced to 6 digits after the decimal point and multiplied by 10.

It should also run with this example: [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47475910/how-to-outputting-of-text-data-to-an-external-temp-file)!

Is there a good solution for that? Many Thanks !!

```js
var x = 0.255400896; //0.855400896 looks good, for example.
document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML =    
    x.toFixed(7) * 10;
```

```html
<p id="demo"></p>
```

Comment: I have no idea what you are asking.

Comment: Look at the attached link, I think then it is understandable, thanks.

Comment: Always pay close attention to data types - check the return value of `x.toFixed(7)`, is it a number? What would you expect to happen if you multiply that by 10?

Comment: ***@julioolvr*** These are small control values (numbers) that need to be increased, so to speak an amplifier of values that arrive.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just take the number toFixed *after* multiplying by 10:

```js
var x = 0.255400896; 
document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML =    
    (x  * 10).toFixed(6);
```

```html
<p id="demo"></p>
```

Comment: ***@Faust*** Thanks for the answer, this is a good approach, I have to apply it in this example. [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47475910/how-to-outputting-of-text-data-to-an-external-temp-file)

Comment: (0.2222222222*10).toFixed(6)  This is working for the example. link !!